# Struggling with promises - how to do something in inner then before outer then gets called?

Tags: javascript, promise

Not sure how to ask this question, and I'm really struggling with promises, so I'll try with a simplified example.

Say I have a function that accepts a callback. In that function, I want to make an asynchronous call that also has a callback, so when its callback gets called, I do something based on its response, then call my callback.

```
someFunction = function(callback) {
    var startTime = (+new Date());
    someAsyncCall(function() {
        var endTime = (+new Date());
        callback(startTime, endTime);
    });
};
```

What the function does is irrelevant, as I am interested in the structure and the sequence of things. But this example merely records the time before and after making the inner async call, then calls the callback to report that info.

Now, to my question, let's say someAsyncCall has been converted to a Promise, and someFunction is also converted to return that promise and does not accept a callback. So, structurally, my function would now look something like this:

```
someFunction = function() {
    var startTime = (+new Date());
    return someAsyncCall();
    // How to capture endTime on then before moving on?
};
```

The problem is, I now want to capture the end time after the someAsyncCall(), and record this data somewhere, presumably on the then condition of someAsyncCall(), before the then condition of someFunction() gets called. How do I do that?

---

UPDATE:
I don't seem to be getting the answer I'm looking for (or it's just not getting through my thick head), so maybe a better way to state my question this way:

Let's start with this bit of sample code:

```
startProcess = function() {
    // Do a bunch of stuff here...
    return doProcess(someParams);
}
```

Ultimately, doProcess returns a promise, which is returned by startProcess. The caller then does whatever it does with it.

Now, I want to wrap some code around doProcess to capture the start and end time, without any disruption to the operation of the existing code. Is there some way I can respond to the completion of doProcess to do something before it resolves the promise, normally, for whatever is calling startProcess? The point is, this function has no idea who is calling it or what the caller is doing with the promise; it's essentially just a wrapper for doProcess.

Comment: there's no promises in the code ... you'd expect a `.then` (inner and outer according to the question title) - or an async/await - your code has nothing asynchronous looking about it

Comment: `So, structurally, my function would now look something like this:` - no, it wouldn't ... `How to capture endTime on then before moving on?` - since you `return someAsyncCall()` there is no "moving on"

Comment: what's inside `someAsyncCall`?  I assume at some point it has `promise.resolve()`, in which case it seems like it would be as easy as adding `callback()` just before the resolve call...

Comment: The point is, someAsyncCall was previously an asynchronous operation that called the callback function that was provided to it (as an immediate function in the example), and someFunction provided a callback that I would call after that. But now someAsyncCall returns a promise, that is also returned by someFunction, so the caller has a promise, now, with a then condition on it. Not sure how relevant it is what someAsyncCall has in it, since it is the caller that is providing the then condition.

Comment: I have resolved my issue by wrapping a promise around the async call. See my solution in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by creating my own promise and returning that, instead of the promise that was coming from someAsyncCall().

I started with this, essentially:

```
someFunction = function() {
    var startTime = (+new Date());
    return someAsyncCall();
    // How to capture endTime on then before moving on?
};
```

And now I have this:

```
someFunction = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var startTime = (+new Date());
        someAsyncCall().then(function(response) {
            var endTime = (+new Date());
            // Record startTime and endTime here (code not shown)
            resolve(response);
        }).catch(function(rtn) {
            reject(rtn);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use async/await... it makes dealing with promises (and situations like this) much easier because it makes everything read like it's synchronous.

Something like this.

```
const someFunction = async () => {
    const startTime = (+new Date());
    await someAsyncCall();
    const endTime = (+new Date());
    return [startTime, endTime]
}
```

Another example without arrow functions and const stuff...

```
var someFunction = async function() {
    var startTime = (+new Date());
    await someAsyncCall();
    var endTime = (+new Date());
    return [startTime, endTime]
}
```

Comment: +1 for async/await.  I think this won't address the main question though, if he's relying on `.then` for some reason, this still won't fire before a `then` method call.

Comment: @JonDeWitt Will not fire before *which* `then` method call?

Comment: Assuming he wants to capture the moment just after his promise resolves, but before a `.then()` method is chained.  There's only one place in the given code `then` can be chained, which is `someAsyncCall().then()`.  I'm still not sure I understand OP's question myself.

Comment: Whatever is calling someFunction is expecting a promise in return - which I guess async provides. But what if I don't want to return the values to the promise? And where do they go when you return them from here? Ultimately, the caller has no awareness of the code I'm trying to wrap around it to capture the start and end times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use a `then` callback on the `someAsyncCall()` promise. By returning the promise chain, `someFunction` returns the promise that will resolve with your callback results, and further callbacks chained to it will happen afterwards.

```
function someFunction() {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    return someAsyncCall().then(function() {
        var endTime = Date.now();
        return [startTime, endTime];
    });
}

someFunction().then(function(arr) {
    var [start, end] = arr;
    console.log(end - start);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand your question now.  To wait for a promise to resolve, and also return another promise without losing the data, there's a solution using a mixture of techniques.  Let's keep `async/await` because they're beautiful. :) In addition, we can send the data along with our promise by passing it to `resolve()`, and we can use that via callbacks passed to `then`.  Run the snippet below to see what I mean.

```js
// demo async call that takes 2 seconds to resolve
const someAsyncCall = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000))

const someFunction = async () => {

  // get the current time
  const startTime = Date.now()
  
  // wait for someAsyncCall() to resolve before moving on
  await someAsyncCall()

  // now that the async call has finished, get the time again
  const endTime = Date.now()
  
  // pass both start and end time as data to resolve
  // this is fed in as the first argument of the callback passed to .then()
  return Promise.resolve([startTime, endTime])
}

// the start and end time were passed from resolve()
// access them from the first parameter of the callback passed to .then()
someFunction().then(data => console.log(data))
```